# Instancing in WCF - Query specific to Mode.PerSession

Tags: wcf-instancing

I am using Instancing mode as PerSession - If a client makes multiple request for a given method - o/p should be incremented as per below code snippet b/c Instancing mode is 
PerSession,

However I am always getting value as 1 for every call, ideally it should be incremented.

Let me know what I am missing

Thanks in advance...

**Server**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServer
{
 [OperationContract]
  int GetData();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class Service1 : IServer
{
  int count = 0;
  public int GetData()
   {
     count++;
     return count;
   }
}
```

**Client**

```
ServiceReference1.IServer obj = new ServiceReference1.ServerClient();
Console.WriteLine(obj.GetData());
Console.WriteLine(obj.GetData());
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the binding you have ? basicHttpBinding does not support PerSession instance mode it defaults to PerCall.

If you have basicHttpBinding change that to wsHttpBinding and try.

Comment: Thx for reply, however I am using binding="wsHttpBinding"

Comment: If that is the case the above code works fine for me. It prints 1 2 and 3. The problem should definitely be with some configuration setting. Sometimes though you may set the binding to wsHTTP it may default to basic for some scenario's..

Comment: hi Suhumar, could you pls let me know the steps that you followed to get above mentioned o/p, also specify the projects that you had taken.. Thanks in advance...